# Best way to check if there is already a token in local storage using use effect in React Context

Tags: reactjs, authentication, local-storage, use-effect, react-context

good day. Is this the best way to check if there is already a token in my local storage in my AuthContext? I used a useEffect hook in checking if the token already exists. Should I change the initial state of isAuthenticated since it is always false upon rendering? Im not sure. Thank you

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [isAuthenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);

    const login = () => {
        setAuthenticated(true);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem("AuthToken");
        if (token) {
            setAuthenticated(true);
        } else if (token === null) {
            setAuthenticated(false);
        }

        return () => {};
    }, []);

    return <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isAuthenticated, login }}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using a state initializer function so you have correct initial state. You won't need to wait until a subsequent render cycle to have the correct authentication state.

```
const [isAuthenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(() => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("AuthToken");
  return token !== null;
});
```

The rest can likely remain the same.

I suggest you also provide a default context value as well.

```
const AuthContext = React.createContext({
  isAuthenticated: false,
  login: () => {},
});

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("AuthToken");
    return token !== null;
  });

  const login = () => setAuthenticated(true);
  
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isAuthenticated, login }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hello Drew Reese, The function inside the useState sounds like a perfect way to implement the checking if the user is already logged in. So I wont have to use the useEffect hook correct? Thank you for this :)